# GKE deployment maxSurge is not taken into account

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I'm using yaml files to make deployments to GKE.

My deployment is configured to use 1 replica, with a HorizontalPodAutoscaler which makes possible for it to scale up to 2 if it's needed.

Normally 1 replica is running, which is totally fine, but when I make a deployment two other pods are created, the deployment waits till at least one of them starts then it stops the old pod.

While I have pretty limited resources I would like to avoid starting two new pods at deployments, I would like to configure the deployment in a way, that it starts **a new** pod and once it has been started stops the old one, then if anytime it will be needed it will scale up to 2 pods by the HorizontalPodAutoscaler. **So I would like to limit the number of additional pods during the deployment to one.** That's why I addedd the **maxSurge** property to the deployement section.

Deployement:

```
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: ...
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: ...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ...
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ...
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: ...
        image: ...
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args: ["--spring.profiles.active=...", "..."]
        env:
        - name: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
          value: -Xmx600m -Xms200m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/dumps
        - name: FOR_GODS_SAKE_PLEASE_REDEPLOY
          value: 'THIS_STRING_IS_REPLACED_DURING_BUILD'
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "50m"
            memory: "800Mi"
          limits:
            memory: "1150Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 4
          periodSeconds: 6
          failureThreshold: 3
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 3
          failureThreshold: 72
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            httpGet:
              path: ...
              port: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: ...
```

HorizontalPodAutoscaler:

```
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: ...
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: ...
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: ...
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 2
  metrics:
  - type: "Resource"
    resource:
      name: "memory"
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 1050Mi
```